# Objective-C out of order execution

Tags: objective-c, compiler-optimization

Can we assume the compiler will never reorder property assignments? Consider the following:

```
@interface ObjA
@property int x;
@property int y; // When YES, x guaranteed to be set to 10.
@end

ObjA a;
ObjB b;

[a addObserver:b forKeyPath:@"y" options:nil context:&context]
a.x = 10;
a.y = YES;
```

Will x always be assigned before y or we do we need to insert a memory barrier?

I know the compiler is supposed to check dependencies to make sure it is safe to assign a.y before a.x but to do that here it would have to look at all the implementations in all observers. If ObjA is part of a library then it can't even know this information until link time, which might be too late to do the reordering? So then is it safe to assume that the compiler will never reorder property assignments? ivars are another story of course.

Comment: I cannot at the moment offer a direct source for this, but you should be able to assume that property assignments cannot be reordered. Property syntax is syntactic sugar for method calls, and because Objective-C is a dynamic language, it is impossible to know what a method call will dispatch to until you try it. Therefore, it is not valid to reorder method calls. If a compiler reordered such calls, it would almost certainly be a bug.

Comment: As you mention, ivars are a different ballpark. Accessing an ivar is performing direct memory access, so the compiler may choose to reorganize those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler cannot re-order property assignments because it cannot know that the code's behavior will remain constant at runtime.

`a.x = 10` is exactly the same as `[a setX: 10]` and, thus, goes through dynamic dispatch.  Because it is dynamic, the potential side effects of said call cannot be known at compile time.

The moment dynamic dispatch is involved is the moment the compiler cannot re-order execution.

Comment: Can we be certain the compiler is not smart enough to analyze objects and figure out if dynamic dispatch is necessary or not for some method calls and inlines them and then does the reordering?

Comment: @JohnK Yes.  Certain.  At any point in time, any misguided coder might deploy code that edits the runtime in highly dubious ways such that any given execution path becomes really convoluted.